# How do I get includeHTML to work inside multiple TabPanels?

Tags: html, r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to include 2 HTML files in different tabPanel separations for a Shiny app. I do that, and one of the html files renders properly but the other one's widgets just do not display. Anyone know why? I have posted the app code below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(div(img(src = "bookofnumberslogo.jpg", height = 50, width = 50) ,"OSC Elections"),
                 windowTitle = "OSC Elections",
    tabPanel(
        title = "House Forecast",
        mainPanel(
            h1("House of Representatives Forecast"),
            p("This forecast is updated daily in accordance with the latest polling data."),
            p("Last Updated: ", date()),
            p("Email oscelections@gmail.com or find us on Twitter at @OSCElections if you have any questions."),
            includeHTML("elexsimGS.html")
    )),
    tabPanel(
        title = "MA Senate Democratic Primary",
        mainPanel(
            h1("Massachusetts Senate Election Democratic Primary Forecast"),
            p("This forecast estimate has last been updated on: ", date()),
            p("Email oscelections@gmail.com or find us on Twitter at @OSCElections if you have any questions."),
        includeHTML("MA-Senate-Model.html")
        ))
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[MA Senate Model.html link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pofwvww3j202yjx/MA-Senate-Model.html?dl=0)
[elexsimGS.html link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vy53tzuaqpabfr/elexsimGS.html?dl=0)

Comment: You should try one mainPanel.  Try `mainPanel(...tabsetPanel(tabPanel(one), tabPanel(two)))`.

Comment: Tried this, it still shows the resulting html widgets as gray. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the tabs to confirm it's not an issue with the underlying html file?

Comment: yes, I did. The output htmls include Leaflet widgets, and they don't display on the second tab regardless of the order.

Comment: could you please also include the content of the html files aswell so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: added links! you may have to download the files as some of the leaflet widgets aren't working in the dropbox link.

Comment: help would be appreciated soon, if you know what to do.